# Moving up the div at window resize without using absolute

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have a structure like this.

```
<div class="container>
 <div class="left-col>
   some content

 </div>

 <div class="right column>
   <div class="login-form">Login Form</div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Above is the structure of my webpage at 700px width and above.. What I wanted to do is whenever the browser width decreases to 480px and below.. the div class login-form would be at the top and then below of it is my left-col.. is there any way for this? I would love to do it without using the position: absolute

if browser width is 480px and below structure would be like this

```
<div class="container>

 <div class="right column>
   <div class="login-form">Login Form</div>
 </div>

 <div class="left-col>
   some content

 </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your HTML have to be like that or can you swap it around? Meaning the html looks different, but you still have the login form on the right on big screens. It's much simpler if the HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="right-col">
    <div class="login-form">Login Form</div>
  </div>

  <div class="left-col">
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Then the CSS:

```
.left-col {
  background: green;
}

.right-col {
  background: red;
}

@media (min-width: 481px) {
  .container {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .left-col {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .right-col {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhummel/4aNjd/

Comment: lol.. thanks for the simple answer..I didn't realize its possible just to swap it directly..

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this and it is called responsive web design. You would use media queries that will tell the page how to behave at certain sizes.

Lucky for you there are more functions to the `position` attribute than `position:absolute;`.In this case, I would use `position:relative;` and move "left-col" down.

Here is a great article to get you started with Responsive web design. [CLICK HERE](http://99designs.com/designer-blog/2012/12/03/responsive-web-design-key-tips-and-approaches/)

Comment: Thanks for that but.. I already know what responsive design and atm Im using media query.. my question is about moving the DIV above whenever window width reaches 480px and below

Comment: With media queries you can set the page however you want. Let me create a quick fiddle for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do those divs show up left and right when the browser is 700px?  If so...

Just have the "right column" div before the "left-col" in your html.  In the css use floats so "right-column" shows up on the right and "left-col" still shows up on the left. I am assuming their widths fit in the container.  Then, within your media query give "right column" float:none and width:100% so that when the browser is less than 480px the form div will show up on top.

note: I think you meant "right-column" and not "right column".

```
<style>
.left-col{
float:left;
}

.right-column{
float:right;
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

.left-col{float:none; width:100%;}
.right-column{float:none;}
}

</style>

<div class="container>

 <div class="right-column>
   <div class="login-form">Login Form</div>
 </div>

 <div class="left-col>
   some content

 </div>

</div>
```